# Can you transfer between a Google and a Trainer Club account?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can you transfer data from your Gmail to Pokemon Trainer Club, because I know you get rewards and I want to switch data so it won't get erased.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at this time you cannot transfer data between accounts, you'll have to pick one and stick with it. Otherwise, you'll be splitting your work between two accounts and only gaining half the benefits.